# Compare two arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, puppeteer

I'm working on puppeteer in nike website.

I'm getting the sizes and stock and showing it as an array,

```
  { sku: 72961, skuname: 'Talla: 6 - Color: Azul', quantity: 2 },
  { sku: 72962, skuname: 'Talla: 6.5 - Color: Azul', quantity: 4 },
  { sku: 72963, skuname: 'Talla: 7 - Color: Azul', quantity: 5 },
  { sku: 72964, skuname: 'Talla: 7.5 - Color: Azul', quantity: 7 },
  { sku: 72965, skuname: 'Talla: 8 - Color: Azul', quantity: 6 },
  { sku: 72966, skuname: 'Talla: 8.5 - Color: Azul', quantity: 5 },
  { sku: 72967, skuname: 'Talla: 9 - Color: Azul', quantity: 8 },
  { sku: 72968, skuname: 'Talla: 9.5 - Color: Azul', quantity: 8 },
  { sku: 72969, skuname: 'Talla: 10 - Color: Azul', quantity: 6 },
  { sku: 72970, skuname: 'Talla: 10.5 - Color: Azul', quantity: 4 },
  { sku: 72971, skuname: 'Talla: 11 - Color: Azul', quantity: 1 },
  { sku: 72972, skuname: 'Talla: 11.5 - Color: Azul', quantity: 2 }
]
```

That is refreshing each 10 seconds so I'd like to find a way that the last array is compared to the previous to know if a new Size or quantity is added

**My code**

```
const pagina = "https://nike.cl"
const producto = "/dm0121-400-nike-dunk-low-retro-qs/p"


const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1440, height: 900});


    while (true) {
    await page.goto(pagina + producto, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' },);
    var SKU = await page.evaluate("skuJson_0")

   let filter = SKU.skus.filter( d => d.availablequantity > 0)
   var SKUfiltered = filter.map(function(d){
    return{
      sku: d.sku,
      skuname: d.skuname,
      quantity: d.availablequantity
    }})

  console.log(SKUfiltered)
await page.waitForTimeout(10000)
```

Comment: loop through the arrays and see if each element is in the other array?

Comment: You want to know if the SKU are the same over the time?

Comment: @jtwalters No, SKU are related to Size (talla) f.e array1 = { sku: 72961, skuname: 'Talla: 6 - Color: Azul', quantity: 2 }, array2 =  { sku: 72961, skuname: 'Talla: 6 - Color: Azul', quantity: 2 },
  { sku: 72962, skuname: 'Talla: 6.5 - Color: Azul', quantity: 4 } so Size 6,5 is "new" so i want to know only the new ones

Comment: Ok, so you want only the new SKUs?

Comment: @jtwalters The new SKUs and the SKUs that availablequantity variates

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is store the SKU data to check if exists previously and if the value are equals.

If the value pass the two checks you could store it in your `"SKU register"`.

As next step, you could make another checks to filter the value. In your case only check if the quantity is zero.

As a complement, if you get many SKU and store a huge maybe you reach the memory limit. So you could remove it if the array is too big. To make that you could create an `Array` to store the values in order and remove if you reach some limit like 1000 elements.

In the next example, I simulate get the data in each `getSKU` execution. You must adapt the code to your solution:

```js
// == FAKE DATA ==
let res_i = 0;
const res_data = [
    [
        { sku: 1, skuname: "1", quantity: 0 }, // empty
        { sku: 2, skuname: "2", quantity: 1 },
    ],
    [
        { sku: 1, skuname: "1", quantity: 5 },
        { sku: 2, skuname: "2", quantity: 1 }, // same quantity
        { sku: 3, skuname: "3", quantity: 0 }, // empty
    ],
    [
        { sku: 1, skuname: "1", quantity: 0 }, // empty
        { sku: 3, skuname: "3", quantity: 3 },
        { sku: 4, skuname: "4", quantity: 3 },
    ],
];
// == END FAKE DATA ==

// An array to save the lastest SKU and a Map to store important values
const SKURegLog = [];
const SKURegdata = new Map();

// A funtion to simulate the data
function getSKU() {
    const SKU = res_data[res_i++]; // Simulate the incoming data

    return SKU.filter((v) => {
        // Get the current SKU in the register
        const curSKU = SKURegdata.get(v.sku);

        // If exists and the quantity is the same, discard
        if (curSKU !== undefined && curSKU.quantity === v.quantity) {
            return false;
        }

        // If the SKU not exists in register add to the array
         if (curSKU === undefined) {
            SKURegLog.push(v.sku);
         }

        // Include the SKU in the register. If the array reach
        // the limit (1000) delete the olders
        SKURegdata.set(v.sku, {quantity: v.quantity});
        if (SKURegLog.length > 1000) {
            const oldSKU = SKURegLog.shift();
            SKURegdata.delete(oldSKU);
        }

        // Check the current quantity
        if (v.quantity === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // Include the SKU
        return true;
    });
}

console.log(getSKU());
console.log(getSKU());
console.log(getSKU());
console.log("= Register data:");
console.log(SKURegLog);
console.log(SKURegdata);
```

**Output:**

```
1: [ { sku: 2, skuname: '2', quantity: 1 } ]
2: [ { sku: 1, skuname: '1', quantity: 5 } ]
3: [ { sku: 3, skuname: '3', quantity: 3 }, { sku: 4, skuname: '4', quantity: 3 }]
== Register data:
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
Map(4) {
  1 => { quantity: 0 },
  2 => { quantity: 1 },
  3 => { quantity: 3 },
  4 => { quantity: 3 }
}
```